# How can I define numbers to say the word equivalent in scheme programming

Tags: scheme, lisp

I want define the digits 0-9 to say the word when used as arithmetic in scheme. for example. (+ 2 5) would be two + five. How can i do this, thanks!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Can you formulate the problem as a set of test cases?

Comment: basically, whenever a number is used within the remaining program, it will replace the number with a word that represents the number. So if I called a function to add 2 parameters together, and i chose (add 5 5) it would return 'ten' as the answer not 10

Comment: So, does the number 5,867,103 have to come out "Five million, eight-hundred and sixty-seven thousand, one hundred and three?"  Does the number 9.1 have to come out "Nine point one?"  Does 2/3 have to come out "Two-thirds?"

Comment: So basically you do `(define (add a b) (number->english (+ a b)))` then make `number->english` that makes one number into a string. You might have noticed that we use special words for 0-19 and that everyting below 1000 can be reused for each 1000 interval so it's definitely a good assignment for recursion. `quotient` and `remainder` are your best friends. Come to think of it this is more like a math question.

Comment: Why would (+ 2 5) be "two + five", but (add 5 5) be "ten"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to repeat my earlier suggestion, but this time as an answer :).

I think that you really need to formulate a set of concrete test cases. The point is partly to help us understand, but perhaps more importantly, to help you organize your thinking.  A test case should include a call to the function, and the expected result. So, for instance, it might look like this:

```
(check-expect (gorzify '(+ 2 5)) "ouch! my toe")
```

... though I'm guessing that's not what your program is supposed to produce.